# How to inject the database connection into a custom service?

Tags: 8, page-controller, dependency-injection

I have a custom module that pulls data from several different external databases that have been defined as connections in settings.php. The current setup includes a series of controllers that have a service I have created called DataAccess injected into them. My DataAccess service has several methods that accept a `$schema` parameter and based on this I use the following each time:

```
$connection = Database::getConnection('default', $schema);
```

I can then query each database as needed with this setup. I thought about injecting Database into my service from the Drupal container, but I would then need a base class like ControllerBase's create method to get that service in the first place. What would be the correct way to do this as it isn't a controller - would I use a different base class here? I am new to Drupal 8 development and trying to ensure I am following the best practices, but at the same time I don't want to overcomplicate things.

Any advice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't inject [`Drupal\Core\Database\Database`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!Database.php/class/Database/8.2.x), it's a container of static functions, constants, & variables for core database functions.

If you'd like to inject the `Connection` object, that is be possible, and is more like something you want (unless you have scenario where  **setting.php** is dynamic an all possible values of `$schema` can't be known).

You can follow the example Drupal sets with the default `@database` class in [**core.services.yml**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.services.yml/8.2.x):

```
  database:
    class: Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
    factory: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection
    arguments: [default]
```

In your **mymodule.services.yml** you can define the factory/arguments for each database connection you have, plus your `DataAccess` service class with the injected connections.

```
services:
  mymodule.database_schema:
    class: Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
    factory: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection
    arguments: [default, schema]
  mymodule.database_schema2:
    class: Drupal\Core\Database\Connection
    factory: Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection
    arguments: [default, schema2]
  mymodule.data_access:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\DataAccess
    arguments: ['@mymodule.database_schema', '@mymodule.database_schema2']
```

From there you can store the database connections in `DataAccess`'s constructor and reference them as required by `DataAccess`'s methods.

Comment: In general good answer but I fear this won't work in this case, $schema is an array and is passed as an argument to the service.

Answer (score 6):

As commented on another answer, the answer here is probably, you can't.

The database API isn't fully converted to use services. I tried to do it for quite some time, in https://www.drupal.org/node/1811730, but didn't succeed and neither did others.

So, for now, you need to use the static methods. The best you can do is wrap it in a method or another service that does just that to simplify mocking it when you want to write unit tests.

Comment: I think that now is possible to inject it, at least it works for me like in my answer.

Comment: There is a change record related to the DB function, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2993033

You can find examples where and how you can get the database connection.

Answer (score 4):

At this moment I'm using this code to inject the database service:

***.services.yml**

```
services:
  onlyone:
    class: Drupal\onlyone\OnlyOne
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager', '@database', '@language_manager']
```

**Drupal\onlyone\OnlyOne**

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, Connection $connection, LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager) {
    $this->entityTypeManager = $entity_type_manager;
    $this->connection = $connection;
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
  }
```

Comment: That's the default database service, sure, that works. The question was as far as I understood about connection to a *different* database. That might also work by defining your own service with the right arguments for that, but it's a bit more complicated than this

Comment: @Berdir I see, maybe was me that misread the question.